# C#. Datetime range with progress bar?

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, progress-bar

So i have some `DateTime's`, `start`, `end` and `now`

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(task.issued_in);
DateTime end = (Convert.ToDateTime(task.issued_in).AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(task.lead_time)));
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

And i wanna do a `ProgressBar`to show the process. (`start` at the beginning of `ProgressBar` and `end` at the `end`)

My idea is `progressBar.Value = (now.hours - start.hours) / (start.hours + end.hours)`

But i can't do it. Maybe there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe progress is a relation of passed hours to total hours:

```
progressBar.Value = (int)((now - start).TotalHours / (end - start).TotalHours);
```

Or thus you calculate end time as `start + task.lead_time`, you can use lead_time as total task time:

```
progressBar.Value = (int)((now - start).TotalHours / task.lead_time);
```